# Overflow in Clojure computation despite using BigInt

Tags: clojure, integer-arithmetic

The following closure computation overflows despite the use of big integers:

```
(defn binomial-coefficient [n k]
  (let [rprod (fn [a b] (reduce * (range a (inc b))))]
    (/ (rprod (- n k -1) n) (rprod 1 k))))

(binomial-coefficient 100N 50N)
```

I could not figure out where the overflow happens. For example, executing `rprod` by itself seems to work.

NB: the binomial coefficient code was taken from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#Clojure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `(rprod 1 k)` with an integer `1` and not a bigint `1N`:

```
(defn binomial-coefficient [n k]
  (let [rprod (fn [a b] (reduce * (range a (inc b))))]
    (/ (rprod (- n k -1) n) (rprod 1N k))))

(binomial-coefficient 100N 50N)
```

The problem lays in `range` function:

```
=> (range 1 10N)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
=> (range 1N 10)
(1N 2N 3N 4N 5N 6N 7N 8N 9N)
```

Alternative solution is to use [`*'`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2a%27), [`-'`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%27) and [`inc'`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/inc%27) instead of ordinary `*`, `-` and `inc` operators, because they have build-in support for arbitrary precision and never overflow:

```
(defn binomial-coefficient [n k]
  (let [rprod (fn [a b] (reduce *' (range a (inc' b))))]
    (/ (rprod (-' n k -1) n) (rprod 1 k))))

(binomial-coefficient 100 50)
```